# Sequelize Many to Many search using OR

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The main idea for my code is to create a search field which I have two many to many fields, and I want to bind the search for the many to many table

I want to select the modelos.nome_modelo_produto field that is inside the table modelos, but never works, because the sequelize dont recognizes the field, even after I mentioned the relationship between the tables:

```
Modelo.belongsToMany(Produto, {through: 'ProdutosModelos'});
Produto.belongsToMany(Modelo, {through: 'ProdutosModelos'});
```

And the idea for the search is this...

```
Table.findAll({
where: {
            [Db.Sequelize.Op.or]: [
                {'nome_produto': Db.sequelize.where(Db.sequelize.fn('LOWER', Db.sequelize.col('nome_produto')), 'LIKE', '%' + req.query.search + '%')},

{'$modelos.nome_modelo_produto$': Db.sequelize.where(Db.sequelize.fn('LOWER',Db.sequelize.col('$modelos.nome_modelo_produto$')), 'LIKE', '%' + req.query.search + '%')}
            ]
}
})
```

But don't works...
Can someone help-me or give-me a way to proceed ?

Comment: I also included the tables with 'include' inside the search params.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have this error, I've checked that when you're using limit or offset tags inside your where there's a annoying error that I could'n solve.

So the tip that I have is to remove the offset and limit, and also rename your table columns to find only by the name, for example, if you have the field tags in the table things, you can rename the tags field to things_tags, if it is a relational field, and when you set the field inside where you can only insert the field name without the table name.